# Insert a variable value in a raw string c++

Tags: c++, json, rawstring

is it possible to insert the value of a variable inside a raw string?
I need to insert the value of my variable "stringa" as a JSON value but my variable contains a lot of escape characters.

try to better explain:

```
nlohmann::json j; //create the json
std::string one = "hello";
j[firstObj] = one;

std::ifstream conf(confPath, std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> a(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(conf), {});
std::string stringa;
  for (auto &v : a)
  {
    stringa += v;
  }
j["conf"] = stringa;
```

i would like "stringa" (which contains a lot of escape characters) to be of type raw string to be able to write it to a file in the next step

Comment: I think there might be a bit of confusion on what a raw string is. Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal for more information. But basically you use raw string in the code for the compiler to convert it into a string. Though maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Look into Base64 as a way of embedding binary data in JSON objects.

Comment: i did this about the Base64 and it solved my problem, i inserted the value as binary in my json.

Anyway it could be interesting if there is still a way to insert a variable value inside a row string